# Did Obi-Wan’s briefing in "The Clone Wars" episode "Phantom Apprentice" take place before or after he said goodbye to Anakin in "Revenge of the Sith"?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

It seems it could be interpreted both ways at this point, but I was wondering if anyone has encountered any strong evidence I haven’t.

Answer (score 3):

### Before

Here's the order of the relevant events as presented in the episode:

- **Obi-Wan's briefing**; Obi-Wan tells Ahsoka to capture Maul to learn more about Sidious
- The briefing is interrupted by Rex, saying there's been an attack
- Ahsoka and Rex leave the briefing to meet Sterling, who tells them about Jesse being captured by Maul
- Maul interrogates Jesse and tells Gar Saxon to kill Almec
- Ahsoka, Rex, and Bo-Katan meet Almec in prison to ask what Maul knows about Sidious
- **Gar Saxon shoots Almec**

Each of the Ahsoka scenes follows from the previous scene, so they must take place in chronological order.

According to the Canon reference book [*Star Wars: Timelines*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Timelines), Almec's death happens before Anakin goes to the opera, which happens before Obi-Wan travels to Utapau. These events are shown as taking place in consecutive order:

> - Code of silence: **On Maul's command, Saxon shoots Almec before Ahsoka can finish questioning him, then makes his getaway.**
> - Maul orders his underlings to go into hiding.
> - A Jedi's temptation: At Coruscant's Galaxies Opera House, Palpatine plays on Anakin's doubt and anger about the Jedi's integrity, guessing that they asked him to be their spy. [...]
> - **Obi-Wan travels to Utapau to hunt for Grievous.**
> - Street fight: Clone troopers, Bo-Katan's commandos, and Saxon's warriors battle in the streets of Sundari, with the Republic's forces winning the day.
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Timelines*, pages 100-101, "Jedi on the Brink"; emphasis added</sub>

Putting these chains of events together, the briefing occurs before Obi-Wan leaves.

Comment: Assuming the episode is chronologically sequenced.

Comment: @Spencer Ahsoka is present in both scenes, and her discussion with Almec about Sidious is directly informed by her conversation with Obi-Wan.

Comment: Please edit that into your answer.

Comment: @Spencer Updated